# How can I show/hide checkbox and textfield in AEM based on the state of other checkbox?

Tags: aem, sling, aem-6

I am trying to achive following results in AEM:

checkbox1 shows/hides textfield1 and checkbox2. Checbox2 shows/hides textfield2.

As for now I am able to show/hide textfield1 and checkbox2 with below code but I am unable to make checkbox2 show/hide textfield2:

```
<items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <displayTextfield1
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/checkbox"
        text="Display textfield1"
        fieldDescription="Check to display textfield1"
        name="./displayTextfield1"
        uncheckedValue="{Boolean}false"
        checked="{Boolean}false"
        value="{Boolean}true"
        granite:class="cq-dialog-showhide">
        <granite:data
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            cq-dialog-showhide-target=".showhide-textfield1"
            cq-msm-lockable="./displayTextfield1"/>
    </displayTextfield1>
    <displayTextfield1Hint
         jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
         sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/hidden"
         name="./displayTextfield1@TypeHint"
         value="Boolean" />
    <textfield1PlaceHolder
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
        fieldLabel="Place holder textfield1"
        name="./textfield1PlaceHolder"
        granite:class="showhide-textfield1">
        <granite:data
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            cq-dialog-showhide-value="true"
            cq-msm-lockable="./textfield1PlaceHolder"/>
    </textfield1PlaceHolder>
    <displayTextfield2
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/checkbox"
        text="display textfield2"
        name="./displayTextfield2"
        uncheckedValue="{Boolean}false"
        checked="{Boolean}false"
        value="{Boolean}true"
        granite:class="showhide-textfield1">
        <granite:data
            cq-dialog-showhide-target=".showhide-textfield2"
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            cq-dialog-showhide-value="true"
            cq-msm-lockable="./displayTextfield2"/>
    </displayTextfield2>
    <displayTextfield2Hint
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/hidden"
        name="./displayTextfield2@TypeHint"
        value="Boolean" />
    <displayTextfield2PlaceHolder
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
        fieldLabel="display Textfield2"
        name="./displayTextfield2PlaceHolder"
        granite:class="showhide-textfield2">
        <granite:data
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            cq-dialog-showhide-value="true"
            cq-msm-lockable="./displayTextfield2PlaceHolder"/>
    </displayTextfield2PlaceHolder>
```

Can you help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can the use acs-commons show/hide touchUI widget: https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/ui-widgets/show-hide-widgets/index.html . The documentation is not entirely complete yet (I am working on that, to include an example) but in the code everything should be explained: https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/acs-commons/touchui-widgets/showhidedialogfields/source/showhidedialogfieldstabs.js

In your case this should work:

```
<items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <displayTextfield1
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/checkbox"
        text="Display textfield1"
        fieldDescription="Check to display textfield1"
        name="./displayTextfield1"
        uncheckedValue="{Boolean}false"
        checked="{Boolean}false"
        value="{Boolean}true"
        granite:class="cq-dialog-showhide">
        <granite:data
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            acs-cq-dialog-dropdown-checkbox-showhide=""
            acs-cq-dialog-dropdown-checkbox-showhide-target=".showhide-textfield1"
            cq-msm-lockable="./displayTextfield1"/>
    </displayTextfield1>
    <displayTextfield1Hint
         jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
         sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/hidden"
         name="./displayTextfield1@TypeHint"
         value="Boolean" />
    <textfield1PlaceHolder
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
        fieldLabel="Place holder textfield1"
        name="./textfield1PlaceHolder"
        granite:class="showhide-textfield1">
        <granite:data
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            acs-checkboxshowhidetargetvalue="true"
            cq-msm-lockable="./textfield1PlaceHolder"/>
    </textfield1PlaceHolder>
    <displayTextfield2
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/checkbox"
        text="display textfield2"
        name="./displayTextfield2"
        uncheckedValue="{Boolean}false"
        checked="{Boolean}false"
        value="{Boolean}true"
        granite:class="showhide-textfield1">
        <granite:data
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            acs-checkboxshowhidetargetvalue="true"
            acs-cq-dialog-dropdown-checkbox-showhide=""
            acs-cq-dialog-dropdown-checkbox-showhide-target=".showhide-textfield2"
            cq-msm-lockable="./displayTextfield2"/>
    </displayTextfield2>
    <displayTextfield2Hint
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/hidden"
        name="./displayTextfield2@TypeHint"
        value="Boolean" />
    <displayTextfield2PlaceHolder
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
        fieldLabel="display Textfield2"
        name="./displayTextfield2PlaceHolder"
        granite:class="showhide-textfield2">
        <granite:data
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            acs-checkboxshowhidetargetvalue="true"
            cq-msm-lockable="./displayTextfield2PlaceHolder"/>
    </displayTextfield2PlaceHolder>
</items>
```

If you want the show/hide of your second texfield to depend on both checkboxes this is also possible and you can check how in the code, it is explained on top

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a custom listener as it will give you more flexibility.

Your listener code can be something like this

```
var $form = $(this).closest("form.foundation-form"), 
var checkBox2 = $form.find("[name='./nameOfCheckBox2']").val(),
var textBox2 = $form.find("[name='./nameOfTextBox2']").val()
```

Then on the basis of variable `checkBox2` show and hide `textBox2`

[Here](http://aemcases.blogspot.com/2019/01/touch-ui-hideshow-fields-inside-coral-3.html) is a blog explaining in more details the steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for more convenient solution here [AEM Authoring Toolkit](https://github.com/exadel-inc/aem-authoring-toolkit)
Look for @DependsOn, @DependsOnRef annotations. Using this plugin you can create TouchUI dialogs for AEM components with using Java classes and manipulate your field using annotations.

DependsOn uses data attributes for fetching expected configuration. To define data attribute from JCR use granite:data sub-node under the widget node. AEM Authoring Toolkit provides a set of annotations to use DependsOn from Java code.
More information about @DependsOn annotation you can find here [DependsOn Plugin client library](https://github.com/exadel-inc/aem-authoring-toolkit/blob/master/aem-authoring-toolkit-assets/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/authoring-toolkit/depends-on/README.md)
In your case it would look like:

```
@DialogField(name = "displayTextfield1", label="Display textfield1",description = "Check to display textfield1")   
@Checkbox
@DependonRef(name="checkFirstCheckbox")
boolean firstCheckbox;

@DialogField(name = "textfield1PlaceHolder", label="Place holder textfield1")
@TextField
@DependsOn(query="@checkFirstCheckbox")
String textfield1;

@DialogField(name = "displayTextfield2", label="Display textfield2",description = "Check to display textfield2")   
@Checkbox
@DependsOn(query="@checkFirstCheckbox")
@DependonRef(name="checkSecondCheckbox")
boolean secondCheckbox;

@DialogField(name = "textfield2PlaceHolder", label="Place holder textfield2")
@TextField
@DependsOn(query="@checkSecondCheckbox")
String textfield2;
```